# ndarray row-wise index of values greater than array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have one array of shape (X, 5):

```
M = [[1,2,3,4,5],
     [6,7,8,9,1],
     [2,5,7,8,3]
     ...]
```

and one array of shape (X, 1):

```
n = [[3],
     [7],
     [100],
     ...]
```

Now I need to get the first index of M >= n for each row, or nan if there is no such index.
For example:

```
np.where([1,2,3,4,5] >= 3)[0][0] # Returns 2
np.searchsorted(np.array([1,2,3,4,5]), 3) # Returns 2
```

These examples are applied to each row individually (I could loop X times as both arrays have the length X).

I wonder, is there a way to do it in a multidimensional way to get an output of all indices at once?

Something like:

```
np.where(M>=n)
```

Thank you

Edit: Values in M are unsorted, I'm still looking for the first index/occurrence fitting M >= n (so probably not searchsorted)

Comment: Your `M` matrix isn't sorted in `axis = 0`, so `searchsorted` wouldn't work generally

Comment: Right, I'm looking for the first index/occurrence of unsorted values. Np.where then, I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start by checking which row indices are lower or equal than `n` and use [`argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to get the first `True` for each row. For the rows where all columns are `False`, we can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to set them to `np.nan` for instance:

```
M = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],
 [6,7,8,9,1],
 [2,5,7,8,3]])

n = np.array([[3],[7],[100]])

le = n<=M

# array([[False, False,  True,  True,  True],
#        [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
#        [False, False, False, False, False]])

lea = le.argmax(1)
has_any = le[np.arange(len(le)), lea]
np.where(has_any, lea, np.nan)
# array([ 2.,  1., nan])
```

Comment: `le = n<=M` is slightly more numpythonic I guess. Also, you may consider replacing `le.any(1)` with the equivalent but cheaper `le[np.arange(len(le)), lea]` (where `lea=le.argmax(1)`).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @panzer, indeed indexing seems faster than using `any`